# Cloudfront TPS for single object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, horizontal-scaling

I understand from the below doc that cloud front can support 100,000 requests per second.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-limits.html#limits-general

Assume 50000 requests per second requests goes to the same object, will the cloudfront scaling still work ?

Comment: What di you mean by 50000 TPS ? 50 000 000 ?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i meant 50000 requests per second.

Answer (score 1):

There does not appear to be an official documented answer to this question.

It *should* work, though, because there is no documented mention of any TPS constraints per object/path, only the limit per distribution... and even that limit of 100,000 can be increased by submitting a request to AWS support, describing your use case... which suggests it's a policy-based limit, not a genuine resource/capacity limit.

CloudFront is a distributed system.  Each of the (currently) 155 global edge location runs independently of the others -- they don't share components, including their caches. (Cache misses are fetched through a second "regional edge" tier, so these are "shared" in the sense that they are accessible by nearby global edges, but this tier is not involved in request processing of global edge cache hits.)  All of this suggests that the achievable TPS (whether per distribution or per object) is not really a function of anything global, so even the documented 100,000 limit is almost certainly a "soft" limit.